# NVD3 Dynamically Selecting Lines in lineChart

Tags: javascript, d3.js, nvd3.js

Is there any way to dynamically (via Javascript) select lines (or radials in the legend) of a NVD3 lineChart? I have been looking through the docs for 30 minutes now, and can't find anything!

**Update:**

To clarify, "selecting line" I mean, there are radial buttons in the Legend, you can select one or many of those radials, and it will only display the selected lines on the graph. I want to create a button that auto selects a subset of those radials, thus only displaying those lines. I guess "select lines" should be "display lines"

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what you mean by select lines? Do you mean get a reference to the path element? If so you can use just use a selector:

```
var line = d3.select("#your-chart nv-series-1 nv-line");
```

Where your nvd3 chart has id="your-chart".

Comment: Thanks for the reply - updated the initial question to clarify.